# how is amcharts4 rectangle html tag dimensions being generated?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

In testing around with rendering on various devices, orientations and source material, I come across an interesting case.

A map of Canada (OK, maybe the planet's 2nd largest country with many islands was not the best pick..) on a phone device with a 375x667 ratio viewport  occupies a space of `327.0333x252.9` pixels, according to the web browser inspector.

This path is nested among a series of g tags.  However, they **follow** (not nested) a tag where a rectangle is defined.  This rectangle's definition `323x400` is not proportional to the path's box dimensions, generating a ton of white space in precious viewport space.

How is this rectangle defined and can it be altered to respect the path's natural dimensions, while fitting in the viewport?

Generated HTML snippet:

```
<g fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="0" focusable="true">
  <rect width="323" height="400"></rect>
</g>
<g>
  <g style="touch-action: none; -moz-user-select: none;" transform="translate(-0.0077,-0.7856)">
    <g>
      <g role="group" stroke-width="0.9960565216800756" aria-label="Series" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1.003959090909091)">
        <g>
          <g clip-path="url(&quot;#id-29&quot;)">
            <g>
              <g>
                <g>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g>
          </g>
          <g fill="#d9d9d9" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="0.9960565216800756" focusable="true">
            <g>
              <g shape-rendering="auto" stroke="#ffffff" fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="0">
                <path d="M0.0076775583937660485,76.05864696757311[...]L0.0076775583937660485,222.15490049518075Z"></path>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g style="pointer-events: none;" opacity="0" transform="translate(101.0077,93.81894045410156)">
        <circle r="10"></circle>
      </g>
      <g role="group" stroke-width="0.9960565216800756" aria-label="Series" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1.003959090909091)">
        <g>
          <g clip-path="url(&quot;#id-82&quot;)">
            <g></g>
          </g>
          <g></g>
          <g fill="#a4a4a4" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="0.9960565216800756" style="cursor: pointer;" focusable="true" fill-opacity="0.8" id="id-156">
            <g>
              <g shape-rendering="auto">
                <path d="M169.91387280358214,136.7602231574686L[...]L242.03978113921693,186.75415049309635Z"></path>
                [...]
                <g fill="#bad533" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="0.9960565216800756" focusable="true">
                <g>
                <g shape-rendering="auto">
                  <path d="M292.10148344508775,306.28047397225953L[...]L279.4704374951894,307.7346226325906Z"></path>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g>
      <g>
        <g>
          <g></g>
        </g>
        <g></g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
```